# Adding application to excluded list using vba (WerAddExcludedApplication)

Tags: winapi, vba, excel, error-reporting

I'm trying to programmatically add a program to the Excluded Application List so that if it crashes, I don't receive the 'Debug/ Close Program' dialog box. It needs to be in vba as it will be part of a larger program written in vba.

Below is my attempt to convert the C++ code found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/bb513617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to vba

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WerAddExcludedApplication Lib "User32" _
        (ByVal pwzExeName As String, ByVal bAllUsers As Long) As Long

Sub test()
    WerAddExcludedApplication "MyApp.exe", 1
End Sub
```

Any anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

abousetta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check declarations. This API is not exported by user32.dll.

Reference said library is wer.dll.

And this function needs Unicode string. So, you have to pass it. Like below

```
s = "myapp.exe"
s = StrConv(s, vbUnicode)
WerAddExcludedApplication(s, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I modified it a bit as follows: Private Declare PtrSafe Function WerAddExcludedApplication Lib "wer" (ByVal pwzExeName As String, ByVal bAllUsers As Long) As Long

Sub test()
  Dim s$, Response
    s = "MyApp.exe"
    s = StrConv(s, vbUnicode)
    Response = WerAddExcludedApplication(s, 0)
End Sub                                                                                                                                      I was getting 'Access Denied' [Error -2147467259 (0x80004005)] until I changed the second parameter to 0 (i.e. stored in HKEY_CURRENT_USER).

Comment: If you want to update the HKLM registry, You have to UAC elevate to Administrator.